# How to prove the Hilbert-S operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

this exercise i haven't an idea ,so i come here .
Let $\left\{ {{e_n}} \right\}_{n = 1}^\infty $are orthonormal basis in a Hilbert space H,A is a  bounded linear operator on H;
if ${M_n} = {\{ {e_1},{e_2}, \cdots ,{e_n}\} ^ \bot }$,when $x\in M_n,\mathop {\sup }\limits_{\left\| x \right\| = 1} \left\| {Ax} \right\| \to 0(n \to \infty )$.
Show that the $A$ is a compact operator

my proof:
$\forall z= x+y$,
$y \in {M_n}^ \bot  = \{ {e_1},{e_2}, \cdots ,{e_n}\} $
$\forall x \in {M_n} = {\{ {e_1},{e_2}, \cdots ,{e_n}\} ^ \bot } = \{ {e_{n + 1}},{e_{n + 2}}, \cdots \} ,\Vert x \Vert=1$,make ${A_N}z = \{ {a_1}{e_1},{a_2}{e_2}, \cdots ,{a_N}{e_N},0,0, \cdots \} $，so $A_N$ is a finite rank operator,and is a compact operator.
$\left\| {Az - {A_N}z} \right\| = \left\| {A\sum\limits_{i = N + 1}^\infty  {{a_i}{e_i}} } \right\| \le \mathop {\sup }\limits_{\left\| x \right\| = 1} \left\| {Ax} \right\| \to 0$.
then i have $\Vert A-A_n\Vert \to 0$
so A is acompact operator

Comment: $\sup\limits_{\left\| x \right\| = 1} \|Ax\|  \to 0$ has no meaning. Are you taking sup over elements of norm $1$ in $M_n$?

Comment: Refer to many books ,i have no idea

Comment: i have an idea :

Answer (score 1):

i have an idea :
on the one hand
$M_1=\{e_1\}^⊥,M_2=\{e_1,e_2\}^⊥,M_3=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}^⊥,\cdots; M_{n+1}\subset M_n,\forall x \in M_n,\Vert x \Vert=1 $,let $a_n=sup\{\Vert Ax\Vert:x\in M_n,\Vert x \Vert=1\}$.
so the sequence $a_n$is decreasing and hence has a limit $a$.
on the other hand
$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}sup\Vert Ax\Vert=0$,so $a=0$,so $a_n$is bounded,$\forall \epsilon >0,\Vert a_n \Vert <\epsilon $;

suppose $T$ is not a compact operator,then $a_n$ haven't a subsequence $a_{n_k}$,so for all subsequence $a_{n_k},\exists \xi>0,\Vert a_{n_k}\Vert>\xi$ .but $\Vert a_n \Vert <\epsilon$,this is not possible；so $T$ is a compactor.